# Ember client deploy does not deploy changes

Tags: ember.js

I try to deploy ember project to AWS S3 and cloudFront. On first deploy all looks good. I added few commits ant try to deploy changes. Deploy fires success but no changes was added to S3 bucket. When i try to build project locally i see my commits in assets. What is wrong with it? Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "camersion-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Small description for camersion-frontend goes here",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
   },
"repository": "",
"scripts": {
"build": "ember build",
"lint:js": "eslint ./*.js app config lib server tests",
"start": "ember serve",
"test": "ember test"
},
"devDependencies": {
"broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
"ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
"ember-cli": "~3.0.2",
"ember-cli-app-version": "^3.0.0",
"ember-cli-babel": "^6.6.0",
"ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^2.0.0",
"ember-cli-deploy": "^1.0.2",
"ember-cli-deploy-aws-pack": "^1.0.1",
"ember-cli-deploy-display-revisions": "^1.0.0",
"ember-cli-deploy-revision-data": "^1.0.0",
"ember-cli-deploy-s3-index": "^1.0.1",
"ember-cli-eslint": "^4.2.1",
"ember-cli-form-data": "^1.1.0",
"ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.1",
"ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.0",
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
"ember-cli-moment-shim": "^3.7.1",
"ember-cli-notifications": "^4.2.1",
"ember-cli-qunit": "^4.1.1",
"ember-cli-sass": "^7.1.7",
"ember-cli-shims": "^1.2.0",
"ember-cli-spinjs": "^1.4.2",
"ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
"ember-cli-uglify": "^2.0.0",
"ember-concurrency": "^0.8.17",
"ember-cp-validations": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
"ember-data": "~3.0.0",
"ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
"ember-inputmask": "^0.6.7",
"ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
"ember-local-storage": "^1.4.1",
"ember-maybe-import-regenerator": "^0.1.6",
"ember-moment": "^7.6.0",
"ember-radio-button": "^1.2.3",
"ember-resolver": "^4.0.0",
"ember-rl-dropdown": "^0.10.2",
"ember-route-action-helper": "^2.0.6",
"ember-route-task-helper": "^0.3.1",
"ember-simple-auth": "^1.6.0",
"ember-simple-auth-token": "^3.0.0",
"ember-source": "~3.0.0",
"ember-truth-helpers": "^2.0.0",
"ember-welcome-page": "^3.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-ember": "^5.0.0",
"loader.js": "^4.2.3",
"pagination-pager": "^3.2.2"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "^4.5 || 6.* || >= 7.*"
},
  "dependencies": {
  "jquery-match-height": "^0.7.2",
  "owasp-password-strength-test": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

and config deploy

```
module.exports = function (deployTarget) {
let ENV = {
build: {
  environment: deployTarget
},
'revision-data': {
  type: 'git-commit',
},
's3-index': {
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
  bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  allowOverwrite: true,
},

s3: {
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
  bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  filePattern: '*',
},
cloudfront: {
  distribution: process.env.DISTRIBUTION,
},
}

if (deployTarget === 'development') {
  ENV.build.environment = 'development'
}

if (deployTarget === 'staging') {
  ENV.build.environment = 'production'
}

if (deployTarget === 'production') {
   ENV.build.environment = 'production'
  }
return ENV
}
```

Comment: I found that issue happens only in development environment. When I deploy in production all works good.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your new assets were compiled and even sent to S3, it just now may be a matter of activating your latest deployment.

Ember-cli-deploy provides two means of activating deploys ([seen here](http://ember-cli-deploy.com/docs/v1.0.x/usage/)).

1. `ember deploy --activate` which "triggers the activate* hooks passing the revision that just got uploaded.".
2. `ember deploy:activate` which "runs a pipeline with the activate* hooks that some plugins implement to make a specific revision as the active one to be served by your backend.

   Takes a mandatory --revision=revisionKey parameter.

   ex.

   `ember deploy:activate production --revision=43cc587`

Before running either command you double check your changes were in fact deployed using the `ember deploy:list` command.